# How to extract a pojo and and a dynamic map in the same select in mybatis mapper?

Tags: sql, jdbc, mybatis

How do I map these dynamic properties in Person class? The number of properties are dynamic and different for different persons.

Mybatis select statement

```
<select id="getPersonDetails" resultMap="person" parameterType="java.util.HashMap">
  select first_name,
  last_name,
  prop1,
  prop2,
  prop3
  . 
  .
  .
  .
  . 
 from commons.person
 where id = #{personId}
</select>
```

POJO Class

```
class Person {

   String firstName;
   String lastName;
   Map<String,Object> props

}

<resultMap="person" type="Person">
  <result property="firstName" column="first_name">
  <result property="lastName" column="last_name">
  **Dynamic properties**
</resultMap>
```

Can't create a static map something like below.

```
<resultMap="dynamicProperties" type="map">
 <result property="prop1" column="prop1">
 <result property="prop2" column="prop2">
</resultMap>
```

Could someone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like an unorthodox table structure.
It still is possible, but with a little bit of verbosity.

```xml
<resultMap="person" type="Person">
  <result property="firstName" column="first_name">
  <result property="lastName" column="last_name">
  <association property="props" autoMapping="true" />
</resultMap>
```

By adding `<association />` with auto-mapping enabled, every column in the result set will be mapped to `props`.

This, however, means that the columns mapped to `Person` (i.e. `first_name` and `last_name`) are mapped to the `props` as well.
To exclude particular columns from auto-mapping, you need to add `<result />` without specifying `property` attribute. e.g.

```xml
<resultMap="person" type="Person">
  <result property="firstName" column="first_name">
  <result property="lastName" column="last_name">
  <association property="props" autoMapping="true">
    <result column="first_name" />
    <result column="last_name" />
  </association>
</resultMap>
```

p.s.
If the variations of properties are known, [discriminator](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#discriminator) could be an option.